# Phonegap json size limit

Tags: android, json, cordova

Does anyone know what the size limit is of a JSON file in PhoneGap 3.0?

I access an external JSON file to populate a carousel gallery. When the JSON file was like 20KB size everything worked perfect but when I tested with 200KB the app began to lag really bad and if I use a bigger file like 500KB, the app gives an alert than it's unable to access the file. I tried to access the file from the server and from direct file in the app... same result.

So did anyone experience a similar problem or does someone know if there is a better solution to this?
Maybe SQLite ? Or how about using MySQL on the server and only exporting the JSON for the necessary query?

Answer (score 0):

This [discussion](http://joapp.com/forums/index.php?p=/discussion/81/recommended-approach-to-load-app-data-from-a-local-json-file-jophonegapios/p1) might help you. What they are saying is to

- break the data up into chunks
- load each in, and save off to SQLite

Hope this is what you looking for. Cheers!

Comment: I saw this discussion but the problem is that I want to know why this happens? When i load the JSON file I store it to HTML5 localstorage ... so maybe it's to big to do this ? but i read over the internet that other people worked with files like 10MB without any problem ... so i dont know where is the problem hiding...

Comment: And what I don't understand, even if the known limit is 10MB(which is for some browser), in this discussion they divide the file on 500KB files, which is your case and it doesn't work too ... so Have you tried to use SQLite ? and did that made it work ?

Comment: @LitBe BTW, some browsers have 10MB limit ... there is no limit or maximum size on the JSON object